# Is there a way to apply a scrollviewer to only part of a treeview item?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview where Each treeview item contains both a signal and a signalname.

I want to have a namepanel inside the treeview item that expands, but i want a scrollviewer to only scroll across the right portion of the panel that contains the signals of the treeviewitem.

Is the only answer to create a custom treeview class? My original idea was to apply two style templates to each of the treeviews so that the expander button is just on one treeview and just make the expansion of one result in the expansion of the other. but ultimately I couldn't figure out a a way to link the items in the two treeviews using triggers so that when one item expands, its counterpart expands.

i also played around with customizing it using just the controltemplate, but I feel like the scrollviewer needs to be placed around only part of the treeviewitem, but there is no way to split the item going to itemspresenter while inside the treeview control template.

Is my best option to just create a custom treeview?

edit:

creating an itemtemplate like suggested will create a separate scrollviewer for part of each item, so I would end up with 6 small scrollviewers. But what I'm trying to do is apply a scrollviewer over the right column of all the items. However, to apply a scrollviewer to all items, I think I would need to place it within the treeview controltemplate. But in the treeviewcontroltemplate you only have access to itemspresenter:

```
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
            <ScrollViewer 
                Focusable="False"
                CanContentScroll="False"
                Padding="4">
              <StackPanel>
                <wpfExp:SignalGraphAxis 
                      PenColor="{Binding ElementName=GraphColorPicker, Path=SelectedColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"                
                      PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                      X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                      MaxTimeValue="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=_SignalDataViewModel.MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                    />
                <ItemsPresenter />
              </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>

          </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Obtained if you will create your custom `TreeView`, you will work it? I think it's best to use a `Template/Style`, and try to make it there. Now a lot of developers for a few changes create their `UserControls`, but I think it's wrong. We need to use a `Template`, or use the `DataTemplate` with the class data. Not just me, but Adam Nathan in his book `WPF 4 unleashed book`, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Itemtemplate. here is an example

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0">
                        <!-- Your Signal data binding -->
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <!-- Your Signalname data binding -->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```